# centering pseudo element "caret" without position relative

Tags: html, css

I have a small caret I am using for a hoverstate on some menu items. Hovering just adds a little class called `menu-caret` which I add a pseudo element to add a little caret.

The css for the carret just looks like so :

```
.menu-caret::before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

The problem I am having is, I would like to center each caret (the menu items are dynamic in size/width, but also keep the integrity of the hover sub menu I have in place here

Here is ia full working example (without the caret fix ) - http://codepen.io/ajmajma/pen/KgGxWL

I know I could do something like this :

```
    ul {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-caret::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

But in adding the position relative, it will mess with the sub menu size (it should be 100% page width). Is there any way to have a centered caret without messing with my sub menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the relative container on which you are creating the caret. For example move it to the `a` tag:

```
.menu-caret > a::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
.menu > ul > li a {
  position: relative;
}
```

## [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGaYRX?editors=1100)